# How to create a ServiceLocator for a particular container in Spring4d

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I need to be able to pass a servicelocator to a class but one which is for a particular container.
I have had a look a the source code but am unable to figure out how to create one for a container other than the global one.

As a work around at the moment I am passing the TContainer but don't like the leak of implementation.

Comment: Why would you want to pass a service locator to a class and not the specific dependencies the class needs or in case they are not determined at creation time factories to create the dependencies that are needed?

Comment: I am using a class helper to get around the problem of not being able to create the application mainform with di and want to switch out the container.